# Watson speech to text angular

Tags: angular, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

i'm currently trying to implement speechToText in a Anuglar Application.

I'm using the following libraries:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-speech
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/watson-developer-cloud

If I start the project I get the following Errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/content-type.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/microphone-stream/microphone-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\microphone-stream'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-microphone.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/format-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/webaudio-l16-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/speaker-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/result-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
ERROR in ./node_modules/watson-speech/speech-to-text/writable-element-stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in 'C:\Projekte\demo\node_modules\watson-speech\speech-to-text'
```

My Import Statements looks like this:

```
import * as recognizeMicrophone from 'watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-microphone';
import {WatsonService} from '../../../services/watson.service';
```

I Am fetching the token via node.JS backend and this works (I guess), the problem occures when I try to regocnize the Microphone:

```
recognizeMicrophone({
    token: token,
    format: true,
    extractResults: true,
    objectMode: true
});
```

Do I miss some dependencies?

Any Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Which Angular version did you try? I tried it with Angular 7 and I got the same error.

Could you please update if you found the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `import recognizeMicrophone from 'watson-speech/speech-to-text/recognize-microphone';` instead of `import * as recognizeMicrophone from ....`. You can see example usage of speech sdk [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs/blob/master/views/demo.jsx#L7) too.
`